# Why isn't the select box reflecting the values shown in alerts? (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I'm debugging some jQuery. Here's the active script snippet:

```
<select id="myselect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="any">any</option>
    <option value="item1" selected="selected">description 1</option>
    <option value="item2">description 2</option>
    <option value="item3">description 3</option>
</select>


function myselect_change() {
    var listid = '#myselect\\[\\]';   // for ease of reading

    var current_sel_in = ($(listid).val() || ['any']); // Ensures correct when none selected
    alert ('selection on entry: ' + current_sel_in.join(", "));

    // if "any" is selected, clear all selections
    if (!jQuery.inArray('any', current_sel_in)) {
        $(listid + ' option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    }

    // if nothing selected, select "any"
    if ($(listid + ' option:selected').length == 0) {
        $(listid + ' option[value="any"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    var current_sel_out = ($(listid).val() || ['any']);
    alert ('selection on exit: ' + current_sel_out.join(", "));
}


$('#myselect\\[\\]').on('change', function() {
    myselect_change();
});
```

I test the code by using clicks and ctrl+clicks to select and deselect options, for example:

- Select multiple items then ctrl-click "any" to add "any" as a selection (expected: "any" selected, but all others deselected)
- Select a single item, then ctrl-click that same item again so nothing selected (expected: "any" selected, all others deselected)

What's weird is that I can see the correct start+end values in the alerts, so the logic seems to be doing what it should. But the GUI isn't showing the programmatically changed options when the event ends. On exit, when it says that "any" is the only selected option, sometimes no options are highlighted in the select box on the GUI.

To confuse things, sometimes the selection is partly modified on the GUI when the alerts are left in but not when they're deleted - sorry that's confused, it seems almost random.

I haven't seen other similar code needing forcible refresh handling, so that doesn't seem to be an issue either.

What's going on?

Comment: Yous hould use `prop()`. Is that what you are looking for: : https://jsfiddle.net/h6w3rmy7/  ???

Answer (score 0):

When any is clicked remove the `selected` attribute for all the `option` except the one with `any`. 
Replace `$(listid + ' option:selected').removeAttr('selected');` with `$(listid + ' option[value!="any"]:selected').removeAttr('selected');`

```js
function myselect_change() {
    var listid = '#myselect\\[\\]';   // for ease of reading

    var current_sel_in = ($(listid).val() || ['any']); // Ensures correct when none selected
    alert ('selection on entry: ' + current_sel_in.join(", "));

    // if "any" is selected, clear all selections
    if (!jQuery.inArray('any', current_sel_in)) {
        $(listid + ' option[value!="any"]:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    }

    // if nothing selected, select "any"
    if ($(listid + ' option:selected').length == 0) {
        $(listid + ' option[value="any"]').attr('selected', true);
    }

    var current_sel_out = ($(listid).val() || ['any']);
    alert ('selection on exit: ' + current_sel_out.join(", "));
}


$('#myselect\\[\\]').on('change', function() {
    myselect_change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="any">any</option>
    <option value="item1" selected>description 1</option>
    <option value="item2">description 2</option>
    <option value="item3">description 3</option>
</select>
```